# Using tikz to draw arrows in text

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am trying to do the following:
[image]

where I want to draw the up and down arrows within text. I first assumed it to be tikz, so below is my MWE. It is weirdly shifted up a little bit, so please help me recreate the above example of arrows.

```
\newcommand{\upspin}{\tikz[scale=0.5]{\draw[-Latex] (0,0) -- (0,0.6cm);}}
This is the spin-up (\upspin) electron and the spin-down (\dspin).
```

Please let me know.

Comment: please provide a test document and not just a fragment, but why tikz rather than `$\uparrow$` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With option `\tikz[baseline=<length>]` and relative length unit `em`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\upspin}{%
  \tikz[baseline=.2em] \draw[-Latex] (0,0) -- (0,1em);}
\newcommand{\dspin}{%
  \tikz[baseline=.2em] \draw[Latex-] (0,0) -- (0,1em);}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1][1-3]
This is the spin-up (\upspin) electron and the spin-down (\dspin).
\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: You can search for `[tikz] baseline` on this site or in the `pgfmanual` to learn more about this option.

**Update:** Following [hpekristiansen's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624313/using-tikz-to-draw-arrows-in-text/624316?noredirect=1#comment1558479_624316), a revised version using `ex` unit. Note the used depth and height setting may not work for all fonts.

One could, of course measure the height and depth of `(` in text mode and use them in `\upspin` and `\dspin`, and even insert the measuring code in latex2e hook `selectfont` (`\AddToHook{selectfont}{...}`) for efficiency concerns.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\upspin}{%
  % depth = .5ex, height = 1.75ex
  \smash{\tikz[baseline=0pt] \draw[-Latex] (0,-.5ex) -- (0,1.75ex);}}
\newcommand{\dspin}{%
  \smash{\tikz[baseline=0pt] \draw[Latex-] (0,-.5ex) -- (0,1.75ex);}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[1][1-3]
This is the spin-up (\upspin) electron and the spin-down (\dspin).
\lipsum*[1][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would `ex` not be a better unit here (I do not know the convention, or if it matters)?

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes `ex` unit is better, though with `ex` you still need to try for an appropriate multiple (`1ex` is not tall enough). The height and depth of `\mathstrut` seems even better.

Comment: Hmm, in usage `(\upspin)` curly braces are in text mode. So `\baselineskip` and `\f@size pt` is safer, maybe even with `\smash{\tikz ...;}`. I mean, a guessed max allowed height and depth in normal text line is, hard to work everywhere.